# Does std::sort change the relative order of equal elements?

Tags: c++, stl

Does the standard guarantee that order of equal elements will not change (eh, forgot the term for that)  by using std::sort or do I need to consider an alternative solution to achieve this goal?

Comment: Given the existence of stable_sort, I would guess "no"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::sort` is not guaranteed to be stable (the term you were trying to think of). As you'd guess, `std::stable_sort` is guaranteed to be stable. `std::stable_sort` also provides a guarantee on worst-case complexity, which `std::sort` does not. `std::sort` is typically faster on average though.

Comment: Note that std::sort is faster in the average case, though.

Comment: @Jerry add this answer to this wiki (so appropriate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596139/hidden-features-and-dark-corners-of-stl

Comment: I expanded on it a bit, but hopefully not to the point that it gets horribly boring...

Answer (score 3):

From C++ reference: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

> Elements that would compare equal to each other are not guaranteed to keep their original relative order.

You might want [stable_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/), but note that it's not as fast (in average)

Comment: Right, better add the 'average' keyword to avoid confusion.

Comment: The comment which pointed it out has probably been removed, thus letting my own pending, that I cannot really removed since it would let yours... oh well :)

Answer (score 2):

No, if you want the guarantee use std::stable_sort

Answer (score 2):

No it explicitly does not guarantee this.  If you need to maintain relative ordering use stable_sort instead.

Documentation of sort which includes reference to equivalent elements

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecdecxh1(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The term for what you're describing is [stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

From SGI's [STL docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html):

> Note: `sort` is not guaranteed to be stable.

Use [`stable_sort`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stable_sort.html) if you need this.